# Location Services issue with API Level 23

Tags: android, gps, android-virtual-device, android-gps

I'm seeing very different behaviors for Location Services between a real device using API level 23 (Android 6.0) and an emulator configured for the same API level.

I have a class with the following declaration:

```
public class GPS implements LocationListener, GpsStatus.NmeaListener {
```

In the constructor are the following:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) GPS.appcontext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener)this);
    locationManager.addNmeaListener(this);
```

Within the AVD emulator, the NMEA listener NEVER fires, but I do see location updates provided through the `onLocationChanged` callback.

On the real device, I *only* see NMEA updates, and the `onLocationChanged` never fires.  Further, if I comment out the `requestLocationUpdates` call in the constructor then I don't get anything (not even NMEA) on the real device.

When using the AVD, I send GPS coords via the simulator.

Is this just a limitation of how the GPS is implemented within the emulator?  Said differently, is there any way to get NMEA sentences at all through an emulator?

Side question:  Why do I have to request location updates AND add an NMEA listener in order to get callbacks on the real device?

Thanks in advance.